# How to skip Authentication UI when reading from keychain

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, keychain

I am trying to skip Authentication UI by using kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip ..like the query below

```
func readExistingCredentials(server: String, completion: @escaping (_: Int,_: String,_: String,_: String) -> Void) {
        let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
                                    kSecAttrServer as String: server,
                                    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                                    kSecReturnAttributes as String: true,
                                    kSecUseOperationPrompt as String: "This allows you to securely sign into your app",
                                    kSecUseAuthenticationUI as String: kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip,
                                    kSecReturnData as String: true]

        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            return completion(400 ,"","", KeychainError(status: status).localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let existingItem = item as? [String: Any],
            let passwordData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data,
            let password = String(data: passwordData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let account = existingItem[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? String
        else {
            return completion(400 ,"","", KeychainError(status: errSecInternalError).localizedDescription)
            
        }

        return completion(200, account, password, "successful")
}
```

but somehow it's retuning from first guard statement with error below

"The specified item could not be found in the keychain."

Not sure if this is right way or not but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you should bother using Keychain directly. You have to definitely know what you are doing to ensure you are dealing with it securely. It's also quite hard to deal with - I recommend using [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess). You can be assured that it's kept safe and secure and you can get your Keychain stuff working in seconds. _This is only a recommendation_

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .. but I really need to use Keychain at the moment.

Comment: `kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip` indicates items that require user authentication are skipped. It's very likely that your 'error' therefor is correct. You cannot access secure data that requires user authentication or bypass user authentication before usage